# Rails request.xhr? is not working

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

Applications - 2 (Java and Rails )

Rails - 3.0.3

Ruby - 1.8.7

Client - Ajax call using Jquery from Java App

Firebug - shows it is actually an Ajax XHR request (XHR tab )

Server - Rails - request.xhr? **false**

**Any gem is missing** for ajax response ( ajax request only from java pp )

My gem list is below:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.3)
arel (2.0.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.3.4)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
crack (0.1.8)
daemons (1.1.0)
delayed_job (2.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.1)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hoptoad_notifier (2.3.12)
httparty (0.6.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
linecache (0.46)
mail (2.2.10)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.2.6)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.3)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
ruby-xslt (0.9.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
```

My controller code is

```
def index
    if request.xhr?
      logger.debug "  Ajax request yes"
    else
      logger.debug "  Ajax request false"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end
```

Jquery code is :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",            
            url:"someurl"

            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');                           

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
```

server log is

```
Started GET "/mozart_content?id=phyp10084_sa102&dt=20130704132018&api=a3aee3fa-567e-11df-be64-7779fa786bb0&sign=WBCbzBY0GDAP6mQVLxcFZX-ES10%3D" for 192.168.42.27 at Thu Jul 04 18:49:44 +0530 2013
  Processing by MozartContentController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"sign"=>"WBCbzBY0GDAP6mQVLxcFZX-ES10=", "api"=>"a3aee3fa-567e-11df-be64-7779fa786bb0", "dt"=>"20130704132018", "id"=>"phyp10084_sa102"}
  Ajax request false
Rendered mozart_content/index.html.erb within layouts/application (149.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 155ms (Views: 154.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: added controller code

Comment: Can you post the server log for one of this requests?

Comment: posted the server log

Comment: @rabinprithvi `requiest.xhr?` is the same as `requiest.env["X-Requested-With"]=="XMLHttpRequest"`. ie: check request headers. Could you check request headers, or try to append this header to your request?

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue...Ajax does not  work on cross domain.

From Firefox Docs,

> HTTP Requests made using the XMLHttpRequest object were subject to the
>   same-origin policy.  In particular, this meant that a web application
>   using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to the domain it
>   was loaded from, and not to other domains.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a POST without specifying data. Change type to GET if you want to do a GET or add data to the request.

Comment: Changed. But still Rails is giving false for request.xhr?

Answer (score 0):

yes it some times give false when posted thorugh $.ajax in place of this you can check request.format == :js

Comment: That's why I made him post his server log, but it clearly shows the server is processing the request as HTML.

Comment: If format.js is placed over format.html  it will process it as js

Comment: Doesn't work: `NoMethodError - private method \`format' called for #<Sinatra::Request:0x000000016afe68>`